# SharePoint Online: Access denied while getting OAuth code

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, oauth

I am trying to get OAuth code to access sites and lists from SharePoint Online. Below are the steps that I have performed:

1. Register application at URL https://adventurer.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
2. Generate Client ID and Secret at above URL and create the application.
3. Request OAuth code from user's credentials by accessing below URL:

https://adventurer.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx?client_id=ebd57c66-97dd-498d-83f5-eedd6536bbc2&scope=Web.Read List.Write &response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost/SharePointOnlineSample

After authentication from SharePoint server, I get error as "access_denied". I don't know what is causing this issue. If I remove the scope from above URL and grant permission to application using below URL:

https://adventurer.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

and below XML:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

It works just fine. But I want to know the correct approach. Why is this XML required to grant permission? Why can't I just get OAuth code using scope in request URL?

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint:

> For add-ins that request permissions on the fly, only a user with Manage permissions to the SharePoint resources that the add-in seeks to access can run the add-in, even if the add-in is asking only for lesser permissions, such as Read.

Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/authorization-code-oauth-flow-for-sharepoint-add-ins:

> In some scenarios, an add-in can request permission to access SharePoint resources on the fly...
>
> **Note**
>
> This type of add-in can only be run by users who have Manage permissions to the resources the add-in wants to access. For example, if an add-in requests only Read permission to a website, a user who has Read, but not Manage, rights to the website cannot run the add-in.

Looks like the user that requests the code does not have Manage permissions on SharePoint and therefore depends on the requested permission to be defined for the app.